# filtering reports at run time based on account

Tags: reporting, administration, configuration

How can I create a report on cases, for example, and then have a filter on account number so that I can show only the cases for a specific account number at run time? Would I need to build a visual force page?

[image]

screenshot of custom link config.

[image]
screenshot of error message when changing account.id to id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a solution to avoid a vf-page you could try it with a custom link

- create a case report and drag the account number to the filters
- create a custom link at account, use URL = e.g. /YOUR_REPORT_ID?pv0={!Id}
- works also on other objects with relation to account, but then you need to adjust the mergefield

this populates your filter dynamically

Comment: i think you could also provide drill-downs using a custom formula-field on account containing a HYPERLINK() pointing to e.g. /00O_YOR_REPORT_ID_5hj?pv0={!Id}

Comment: The below blog will provide you more details on the report parameters and how you can use it.

http://forcecrazy.blogspot.com/2011/09/some-report-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: thanks Uwe, can you be more specific with the URL, I am getting a fail with mine even though I follow your instructions: my URL is "/00Om0000000JQzp_5hj?pv0={!Account.Id}"

Comment: @UweHeim BTW, I created the report and added the Account Id field as a filter, see screenshot added to my question - is the correct thing to do, my thinking is that when you click on the link from the account record it takes the account id and passes it to the report as the filter parameter.

Comment: @Bartley Yes it should work that way. Do you have any problems? Does the link+filter work as expected?

Comment: If you are on Account, then please try it just /00Om0000000JQzp_5hj?pv0={!Id} instead of /00Om0000000JQzp_5hj?pv0={!Account.Id} because you are already in the Account scope. The rest looks fine at the first glance.

Comment: @UweHeim I get an error message if I try to save with just Id instead of Account.Id, I have inserted error message to my question

Comment: @UweHeim, I thoroughly checked over the URL Syntax and stripped back to just the report, I had success with this and saw that there was _5Hj which should not have been there, I removed this and ran the report from the link with success. I then added the account parameter and again had success, filtering the report by account of the record that I was on.

Comment: @Bartley you had those problems because of my bad example. Sorry for that. I have tried to improve it so that others won't fall in the same trap. Good to here that it finally worked out for you!